# Android PhoneGap jQuery AJAX - Unexpected Token < Error

Tags: jquery, android, ajax, mobile, cordova

I have been reading all over trying to find a reason why my AJAX, getJSON callback, JSONP and POST calls to my web server from my mobile phonegap android app is not working.  I have tried every trick in the book and all of them work perfectly when using a standard web browser.  Has anyone come across the ...

```
Uncaught SyntaxtError: Unexpected token < at http://www.google.com
```

.. error before? I have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`  in my AndroidManifest.xml.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[From here](http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/8919926330fed7e9)

> It certainly seems to be an issue where polling is not detected 
>   properly.  Can you set: 
>   PhoneGap.UsePolling=true; 
>   In your phonegap.{ver}.js file?

Comment: I am using the latest PhoneGap 1.5.0 that comes with Cordova instead of phonegap.js.  Any suggestions on how to turn on UsePolling with the latest version?

Comment: Ok, I don't know much about Cordova so I'll take a look at the js and I'll tell you.

Comment: Thank you.  After some debugging I have change the code an there is no longer a unexpected token error.  However the GET jquery request is still failing through the PhoneGap app.  Here is the new problem, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9676616/phonegap-1-5-0-android-cordova-ajax-json

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts.

Make sure you have the contentType set correctly in the options for your jquery ajax request. Also Android has an ajax bug with caching. So also set the cache : false option.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I added the content-type header and just added clearCache to the AndroidManifest.xml.  No luck