# PhoneGap 1.5.0 Android Cordova AJAX JSON

Tags: jquery, android, ajax, cordova

I have been trying to send an AJAX request for over a day now through an Android PhoneGap App running the latest 1.5.0 PhoneGap.  I have tried a GET, POST, AJAX, getJSON request from the stand jQuery package (not jQuery Mobile).  All of it works in the a standard browser but nothing is working from the App.

**Here is my latest jQuery AJAX Code**

```
$.get(
    'http://www.fakedomainname.com/ajax/user_login.php',
    $('#emailLoginForm').serialize(),
    function(json) {
        //console.log(json);
        alert(json.status);
    },
    'json'
);
```

**Here is my PHP code**

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']); 
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json'); 

$output['status'] = 99; //new user  

echo json_encode($output);
```

**I have added clearCache to my AndroidManifest.xml**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.clearCache();
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
```

**I have added this to /res/xml/cordova.xml**

```
<access origin=".*"/>
```

What else am I missing?  I cannot get the GET jQuery request to successfully alert anything?  I have made sure cache is cleared.  I have whitelisted the cross domain question in header of my php file and in my cordova.xml file.  I am lost, has anyone successfully created an AJAX call with the new PhoneGap 1.5.0?

***The error was my fault.  The URL I was hitting also included a function that checked to see if the user-agent was a mobile device.  If so it would redirect the call to a mobile friendly version of the domain/site I was requesting.  As a result my json value was never being returned.  I removed the mobile device check function and all of my settings above worked perfectly fine.***

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the Internet permission to your Android manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
```

If so, is it in the right place (**not** within the application tag)?

Comment: Unfortunately I do already have that in my AdroidManifest.xml.  I wish that was the answer.

Comment: How about trying to add an error callback to the jQuery AJAX call?  That might give you more details on what exactly is failing.

Comment: I just updated my jQuery to 1.7 to enable the error function of GET ajax request.  The error message that was returned was "Parsing JSON Request Failed."  When I test this in a normal browser things work perfectly fine, however through the PhoneGap App it fails?  My PHP code is above.

Comment: Do you need to do something on the server side to allow cross domain access?  What is the response that your server is sending back?  It might be easiest to log this from the server side or you can use Wireshark to see what response is coming back to your emulator.

Comment: I figured it out!  It was a horrrrible mistake on my part.  The domain/site I was hitting has a config.php file that I had included at the top of the json request file because it has database connection settings in it, however, it also included a mobile user-agent check function.  When it finds that the user is coming form a mobile phone it redirects the user to a mobile friendly site.  So it was redirecting my call and not returning the json response.  Sorry to waste your time and taking you for helping me debug this issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
super.init(); 
super.clearCache();
```

You are missing the `init`. Try adding the above.